# If-Else Statement Error

Tags: php

The program should be like this :

- The code will check if there's any file available for uploading.
- If there's any file found. It will upload and the texts will save in the database.
- But if there's no file found, it will not upload and the path will not also save but the texts will still save in the database.

What really happens:

- The texts are saving
- The image path is still saving! So it'll be a problem for retrieving the image on the later part.

As you noticed:

- I removed the `avatar_image_path` on `if` that's how I thought for the image path not to be saved but it is still saving.

Code:

```
 if ($_FILES["file"]["name"] == 0)
    {

    $updateQuery = "UPDATE  `users`.`info` SET  `password` =  '$newPass',`contact_number` =  '$newConNum',`user_address` =  '$newAdd',`email_address` = '$newEmail', WHERE  `info`.`username` =  '$username' AND  `info`.`password` =  '$userpass' AND `info`.`firstname` =  '$firstName' AND  `info`.`lastname` =  '$lastName' AND  `info`.`admin_level` =$adminLvl AND  `info`.`contact_number` =  '$ConNum' AND  `info`.`user_address` =  '$usrAdd' AND `info`.`avatar_image_path` =  '$avaImgPth' ";
    $executeQuery=$con->query($updateQuery);
    echo "Profile successfully UPDATED!";

      }

 else
    {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "avatar/owner-".$_SESSION['username']."-fname-".$_SESSION['fname']."-l_name-".$_SESSION['lname']."-filename-".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $updateQuery1 = "UPDATE  `users`.`info` SET  `password` =  '$newPass',`contact_number` =  '$newConNum',`user_address` =  '$newAdd',`email_address` = '$newEmail',`avatar_image_path` =  '$filepath' WHERE  `info`.`username` =  '$username' AND  `info`.`password` =  '$userpass' AND `info`.`firstname` =  '$firstName' AND  `info`.`lastname` =  '$lastName' AND  `info`.`admin_level` =$adminLvl AND  `info`.`contact_number` =  '$ConNum' AND  `info`.`user_address` =  '$usrAdd' AND `info`.`avatar_image_path` =  '$avaImgPth' ";
    $executeQuery1=$con->query($updateQuery1);

    echo "Profile successfully UPDATED!";
    }
```

Comment: 0 is a strange name for a file.

Comment: You ask about wrong condition in the if statement.

Comment: Sorry about those. I'm running out of time for the submission of this. I also tried this `if($_FILES['file']['name'] == "")` but the problem is still the same.

Comment: Do var_dump($_FILES) to see what params come in. Regarding them do if statement.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider it doesn't matter null == false == 0 == "0" == "" so it's not a big trouble until statement is not "===" (strict).

Comment: @user3437929 also check this http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php and this http://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.files.php

Comment: The code of your form might be relevant as well.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to save old profile image in hidden field.

```
<html>
<input type="hidden" name="old_image" value=<?php echo $row['image'];?>/>
<input type="file" name="new_image"/>
</html>
```

now when you submit a form then check

```
<?php
if($_FILES['new_image']['name']!="" && $_POST['old_image']=="")
{
echo "upload process...";
}
else
{
echo "save old image in database.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I can't fully understand your tip.

Comment: i think your issue is when user update his/her profile then profile image uploaded wrong if he/she not uploaded or not stored proper value in database so that use this script.